# JsonSchema Array of mixed items in fixed position with only second item required

Tags: java, json, schema, jsonschema

I need to define a Json Schema which accepts an array. This array can have one of the following structures:
1: `["StringConstant",{someKeys:someValues},"StringConstant","StringConstant"]`
2: `[{someKeys:someValues},{someKeys:someValues},...]`
3: `["StringConstant",{someKeys:someValues},"StringConstant","StringConstant","StringConstant",{someKeys:someValues},"StringConstant","StringConstant",...]`
4: `["StringConstant",{someKeys:someValues},"StringConstant","StringConstant",{someKeys:someValues},...]`

The `StringConstant` are all the same and the Objects `{someKeys:someValues}`all have the same keys.

Basically the Object `{someKeys:someValues}` can stand on its own or with a leading `StringConstant` and two trailing `StringConstant`

Currently I have:

```
{
 "type": "array",
 "items" : [
      {
       "const": "first"
      },
      {
       "type": "object",
       "properties":{...}
      },
      {
       "const": "second"
      },
      {
       "const": "third"
      }
    ],
 "additionalItems": false       
}
```

But this schema requires the constants to always be present.
Is there a way to define and validate the required structure with JsonSchema?

One possible way I found is to define the array objects as `anyOf` and write the validation for the leading and trailing constants myself.

Comment: I'd go with `anyOf` to define one sub-schema like you already have and some more for the optional cases. I don't think there's a simpler solution.

Comment: When the value of `items` is an array, you're using the tuple form, which is not what you want. Here's an explanation of tuple form validation: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#tuple-validation - Keep in mind these docs are for modern JSON Schema (2019-09 or newer) and you're using draft-04.